# Highcharts, arithmetic operation between two graph's series points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Assuming that I have this two series shown in graph. What I'm trying to do is to divide User and Session values that are in the same interval on the graph and show on hover.

Here's the demo code and below there's the fiddle link.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        scrollablePlotArea: {
            minWidth: 700
        }
    },

    data: {
        csvURL: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/' +
            '057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/analytics.csv',
        beforeParse: function (csv) {
            return csv.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n');
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Daily sessions at www.highcharts.com'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Google Analytics'
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
        tickWidth: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 3,
            y: -3
        }
    },

    yAxis: [{ // left y axis
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 3,
            y: 16,
            format: '{value:.,0f}'
        },
        showFirstLabel: false
    }, { // right y axis
        linkedTo: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3,
            y: 16,
            format: '{value:.,0f}'
        },
        showFirstLabel: false
    }],

    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        borderWidth: 0
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {

            },
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'All sessions',
        lineWidth: 4,
        marker: {
            radius: 4
        }
    }, {
        name: 'New users'
    }]
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wd1qpdsj/1/)

As you see in the fiddle, if you hover the graph, you see that day's session and user values. Can I also add a Ratio which is Session / User ?

I can't seem to find related example in the docs. Any tip is appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [tooltip.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter)

```
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    crosshairs: true,
    formatter: function() {
      var points = this.points;
      var str = '<span style="font-size:.85em">' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A %b %e, %Y',
        new Date(points[0].x)) + '</span><br>'
      points.map((el) => {
        str += '<span style="color:' + el.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + el.series.name + ': <b>' + el.y + '</b><br/>'
      })
      str += '<span style="color:red">\u25CF</span> ' + points[0].series.name + '/' + points[1].series.name + ': <b>' + (points[0].y / points[1].y).toFixed(2) + '</b><br/>'
      return str
    }
  },
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2zpunp3/) demo

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to create the tooltip by yourself. There's a `formatter()` method to let us create a tooltip that we want.

```
formatter: function() { 
  var tooltip = '<span style="font-size:10px">' + moment(this.x).format('dddd, MMM DD, YYYY') + '</span><br>';
  for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
    let point = this.points[i]
    tooltip += '<span style="color:' + point.series.color + '">●</span>';
    tooltip += point.series.name + ': ';
    tooltip += '<b>' + point.y + '</b><br>';
  }
  let ratio = (this.points[1].y / this.points[0].y).toFixed(2);
  tooltip += '<span>Ratio: <b>' + ratio + '</b></span>'
  return tooltip;
},
```

I use **moment.js** to format the datetime and `this.x` here is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

`moment(this.x).format('dddd, MMM DD, YYYY')`

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    scrollablePlotArea: {
      minWidth: 700
    }
  },

  data: {
    csvURL: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/' +
      '057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/analytics.csv',
    beforeParse: function(csv) {
      return csv.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n');
    }
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Daily sessions at www.highcharts.com'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: Google Analytics'
  },

  xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
    tickWidth: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    labels: {
      align: 'left',
      x: 3,
      y: -3
    }
  },

  yAxis: [{ // left y axis
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    labels: {
      align: 'left',
      x: 3,
      y: 16,
      format: '{value:.,0f}'
    },
    showFirstLabel: false
  }, { // right y axis
    linkedTo: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    opposite: true,
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -3,
      y: 16,
      format: '{value:.,0f}'
    },
    showFirstLabel: false
  }],

  legend: {
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    borderWidth: 0
  },

  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() { 
      var tooltip = '<span style="font-size:10px">' + moment(this.x).format('dddd, MMM DD, YYYY') + '</span><br>';
      for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
        let point = this.points[i]
        tooltip += '<span style="color:' + point.series.color + '">●</span>';
        tooltip += point.series.name + ': ';
        tooltip += '<b>' + point.y + '</b><br>';
      }
      let ratio = (this.points[1].y / this.points[0].y).toFixed(2);
      tooltip += '<span>Ratio: <b>' + ratio + '</b></span>'
      return tooltip;
    },
    shared: true,
    crosshairs: true
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      point: {

      },
      marker: {
        lineWidth: 1
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'All sessions',
    lineWidth: 4,
    marker: {
      radius: 4
    }
  }, {
    name: 'New users'
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/js/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/js/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/css/highslide.css" />

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```